# Does allowing few character's repetitions make passwords weak?

Tags: passwords

I wonder how character's repetition affect passwords strength? (i'm not referring here to passwords like "IcfIq7IkIRI4" with too much repetitions)
Is there some brute force filters that make breaking a password like "jQ3nSeRG3Q" easier than "jQ8nSeRG3L" ?

Comment: @John is correct. Passwords are strong if they are lengthy enough and don't contain words or popular misspelled versions of words. Repeating certain parts of the password will work unless that part itself is commonly used in passwords. That said, if your password once leaked, hackers may try combination of the repeated pattern if it is very obvious. If your password would be: FlowerRectangle123! it is actually something that will be broken quickly. If you change it to Fl0w3rR3ct@ngl3! it is still easily broken, because that's what everyone does. Switching letters around will still work though.

Comment: I use this site to generate strong passwords>>>>https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm